# Browse and compare two arrays

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, zero

I need to compare an array that comes from a query, with a base array where I have the values that could have the array that comes from the query, the question is how to go through and compare the two arrays so that I get zero where the values do not match And give me the value of the array ?.

this is my code:

```
public function age_range_men()
{       
    $type = 'brands';
    $id_array= 75;
    $date_start= '2017-01-02 00:01:00';
    $date_end='2017-03-31 23:59:59';
    $datos = $this->statistics_model->range_age_men($type, $id_array, $date_start, $date_end);

    $result = array();

    foreach($datos as $dato) {
        $result[] = array((string)$dato->rango, (int)$dato->conexiones );
    }

     $base= array(array('12 a 17'), array('18 a 24'),array('25 a 34'), array('35 a 44'), array('45 a 54'),array('55 a 64'),array('mas de 65'));

    $res = array();

    foreach ($base as $base1) {
    // print_r($base1[0]);
    //       echo "<br>";
        foreach ($result as $result2){      
            if ($base1[0] == $result2[0]){
            }else{
                echo 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> [The first line is $result and the second line is $base][1]
>
> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC5Ps.jpg

Comment: Can you show what is in `$result`? is it like the values in `$base`? Is there a reason you have base as a multi-dimensional array? Really seem un-needed.

Comment: yes, the first line is $result and the second line is $base

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I follow. I would first like to know why you have a multi-dimensional array for base.

Comment: Please review the image :)

Comment: Why not have this as `array('12 a 17', '18 a 24', '25 a 34'...)` This eliminates that extra single indexed array.

Comment: But, it is necessary to compare the positions of the other array

Comment: $result is the result of the query, comes from arriva, before it was done foreach, and $base is the base array with which to compare the $result to put zeros in the pointers that do not match the $base array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. Create an associative array for results. Make `$base` a list of keys rather than a strange multi-dimensional array. Check for the key in an array. I have the else echo 0 I have no idea what you want if it exists.

```
<?php

function age_range_men(){     

    $type = 'brands';
    $id_array= 75;
    $date_start= '2017-01-02 00:01:00';
    $date_end='2017-03-31 23:59:59';
    $datos = $this->statistics_model->range_age_men($type, $id_array, $date_start, $date_end);

    $result = array();


    foreach($datos as $dato) {
        $result[(string)$dato->rango] = (int)$dato->conexiones; // Note this is now using a key
    }

    //This is no longer a multi-dimensional array just the keys we need
    $base= array('12 a 17', '18 a 24','25 a 34', '35 a 44', '45 a 54','55 a 64','mas de 65');

    $res = array();

    foreach ($base as $key) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $results)){
            //CODE???
        } else {
            echo 0;
        }
    }
}

age_range_men();
```

Comment: But in the variable $results the result is random, that depends on the query, the value that arrives will never be the same, therefore could not put a specific name.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean a specific name?

Comment: See what I did in my edit. I cannot make the same calls you could so used your image data to test.

Comment: haaa ok ok I understand your suggestion,  I'll try right now

Comment: @Dave Did this work? If so you should upvote and accept. Or let me know why it did not so I can review. You seem to be creating a habit of not doing this.

Comment: yes, I sorry dont work yesterday but the the problem is almost solved thanks